# Find the sum of all the primes below two million. Project euler, C

Tags: c

So, everything seems to be working nicely, but the program doesn't give me the correct answer. Mine is 142,915,960,832, whereas it should be 142,913,828,922. The differece is 2,131,910 (if I still can subtract numbers on paper haha) and I have no idea where did I get those two millions. Could anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BELOW 2000000

int isaprime (int num);

int main (void) {

    int i;
    float sum = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < BELOW; i++) {

            if (isaprime(i) == 1) {
                    sum = sum + i;
                    printf ("\n%d\t%.1f", i, sum);
            }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int isaprime (int num) {

    int i;

    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                    return 0;
            }
            else {
                    ;
            }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's probably because of that `else { ; }` part... :P

Comment: (Nah, seriously, I'd add one to that `sqrt()`. Floating-point numbers aren't exact, maybe you are missing some primes because of truncation to integer.)

Comment: The thing is, I am not missing primes, I have 2 millions more of them than I should have haha.

Comment: A `float` only has about 7 decimal digits of precision. I suggest you change `sum` to a large _integer_ type such as `long long`.

Comment: @LeaPetrášová Actually, that makes sense. In fact you are getting some false **non-primes** pretending to be primes if they have a factor near `sqrt(n)` which isn't reached because of the truncation. Then your for loop doesn't get to the `return 0;` part, and you are returning 1 confirming that the number is a prime.

Comment: I'd use the Sieve of Eratosthenes (or something similar like the Sieve of Atkin), and avoid the divisions, floating point, etc. This will probably also gain considerable speed (e.g., gets the correct answer in about 0.04 seconds on my laptop).

Comment: Also, using `long` instead of `float` seems to result in the correct answer (just tested).

Comment: @H2CO3: though you probably want `long long` to assure it's large enough (`long` only assures 32 bits, which will overflow).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Running on a platform on which `long` is 64 bits wide :) But true in general.

Comment: @H2CO3: Sorry -- probably should have been directed more at the OP than you personally (since having gotten the correct answer shows your `long` actually is 64 bits).

Comment: @H2CO3 If , the problem is **float** type , then why a overflow vaule show so normal . Just change form 142,915,960,832 to 142,913,828,922, not any negative number .

Comment: @LidongGuo I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @H2CO3 and JerryCoffin: thanks guys! I added 1 to the sqrt part and changed the type - got the right answer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace the type became a long long thanks to you. Sorry ^^

Comment: @LeaPetrášová So why you add 1 to the sqrt ? what output is if you keep 2 in the sqrt after change the type ?

Comment: @Lidong Guo: It doesn't overflow with 32-bit `float`. It loses precision.

Comment: @H2CO3 I feel confuse . I always think , if the type overflow, it will give me a big negative number.

Comment: @Lidong Guo: It does *not* overflow.

Comment: @LidongGuo: That might be correct for a `signed integer` type, you should do some research on `floating point` types.

Comment: @Jason Thanks , now I understand . well , learn a lot today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`float`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) as the `sum` is the problem. The largest integer `k` such that all integers from `[-k, k]` are *exactly* representable in 32-bit float is 2^24<sup>1</sup>; after that you will start losing precision in some integers. Since your sum is outside that range that, by an absurd margin, you lose precision and all bets are off.

You need to change to a larger type like `long` (assuming it's 64-bits on your machine). Make the change, and you'll get right answer (as I did with you code):

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-190-10 ~]$ cat -n euler.c
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <math.h>
     3  
     4  #define BELOW 2000000
     5  
     6  int isaprime (int num);
     7  
     8  int main (void) {
     9  
    10      int i;
    11      long sum = 0;
    12  
    13      for (i = 2; i < BELOW; i++) {
    14  
    15              if (isaprime(i) == 1) {
    16                      sum = sum + i;
    17              }
    18      }
    19      printf("sum: %ld\n", sum);
    20  
    21      return 0;
    22  }
    23  
    24  int isaprime (int num) {
    25  
    26      int i;
    27  
    28      for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++) {
    29              if (num % i == 0) {
    30                      return 0;
    31              }
    32              else {
    33                      ;
    34              }
    35      }
    36  
    37      return 1;
    38  }
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-190-10 ~]$ gcc euler.c -lm
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-190-10 ~]$ ./a.out
sum: 142913828922
```

<sup>1</sup>: 23 explicit bits in the mantissa plus one hidden bit.

Comment: I did change the type to unsigned long long (oh, just to be sure) and it produced the right answer. Thanks for your help.
// and it was not 142913828920, but 142913828922 - I missed the first prime. O:)

Comment: Fixing that problem will give you the right answer. But you'll still be deadly slow. You need to switch to a Sieve to get reasonable performance (in C, reasonable for this task is instantaneous; i.e., it should print the result before your finger comes off the enter key).

Comment: While correct, the point of the question is why OP's code not printing the right output. Finding or checking small primes quickly is something that has been covered amply on SO previously. No need to duplicate here.

Answer (score 6):

As @LeeDanielCrocker suggested, here is an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/sieve-of-eratosthenes) that solves the problem instantaneously:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ISBITSET(x, i) (( x[i>>3] & (1<<(i&7)) ) != 0)
#define SETBIT(x, i) x[i>>3] |= (1<<(i&7));
#define CLEARBIT(x, i) x[i>>3] &= (1<<(i&7)) ^ 0xFF;

long long sumPrimes(int n) {
    char b[n/8+1];
    long long i, p;
    long long s = 0;

    memset(b, 255, sizeof(b));
    for (p=2; p<n; p++) {
        if (ISBITSET(b,p)) {
            //printf("%d\n", p);
            s += p;
            for (i=p*p; i<n; i+=p) {
                CLEARBIT(b, i); }}}
    return s; }

int main(void) {
    printf("%lld\n", sumPrimes(2000000));
    return 0; }
```

At [ideone](http://ideone.com/2NRLTz), that returns in thirty milliseconds. The optimized version shown below, which sieves only on odd numbers and handles 2 separately, runs in zero time (less than ten milliseconds) at [ideone](http://ideone.com/2fkX4Y).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ISBITSET(x, i) (( x[i>>3] & (1<<(i&7)) ) != 0)
#define SETBIT(x, i) x[i>>3] |= (1<<(i&7));
#define CLEARBIT(x, i) x[i>>3] &= (1<<(i&7)) ^ 0xFF;

long long sumPrimes(int n) {
    int m = (n-1) / 2;
    char b[m/8+1];
    int i = 0;
    int p = 3;
    long long s = 2;
    int j;

    memset(b, 255, sizeof(b));

    while (p*p < n) {
        if (ISBITSET(b,i)) {
            s += p;
            j = (p*p - 3) / 2;
            while (j < m) {
                CLEARBIT(b, j);
                j += p; } }
        i += 1; p += 2; }

    while (i < m) {
        if (ISBITSET(b,i)) {
            s += p; }
        i += 1; p += 2; }

    return s; }

int main(void) {
    printf("%lld\n", sumPrimes(2000000));
    return 0; }
```

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog; it describes both algorithms given above, covers all the algorithms you will need to solve the prime-number problems at Project Euler, and includes source code in C and four other languages.

Comment: Your macros are definitely bogus: remove the `;` and parenthesise the arguments and the expansion. What an unconventional bracing style!

Answer (score 3):

Please try this way, fast and simple:

```
int const MAX = 2000000;

int checkPrime(int n){
    int range = n;
    for (int i = 2; i < range; i++){
        if (n%i == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        range = n / i;
    }
    return 1;
}

int solution(){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; i++){
        if (checkPrime(i) == 1){
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This work. However whats the logic behind range=n/i ? 

I can see that if ranged is decreased below the iteration you have a prime , but how can you explain that logic? It seems a bit blurry to me.

Comment: `range = n / i;` is a way to reduce the range such that `i * i < n`. It has 2 problems: 1) the comparison should be `i <= range` otherwise you may count as primes some numbers that are the square of large primes. 2) division is slower than multiplication: you should simply use `i * i <= n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 2000001
long long a[MAX],c=0;
main()
{
     long long i=0,k,j,p,temp=0;
    long long inc=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    a[i]=i;
    for(j=2;j*j<MAX;j++)
    {   
        temp=j;
        inc=2*temp;
        k=((MAX-1)/temp)-1;
        while(k)
        {
            printf("%d",inc);
            printf("\n");
            if(a[inc]!=0)
            a[inc]=0;
            inc+=temp;
            --k;
        }
    }
    for(p=0;p<MAX;p++)
    {
        if(a[p]!=0)
        c=c+a[p];

        printf("%lld",a[p]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    printf(" The sum is : %lld",c-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sieve algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) as this would be the fastest of all:-

**In C++**

```
std::vector<int> generate_primes( int n )
{
    std::vector<bool>sieve( n, true ) ;
    for( std::size_t i = 2 ; i < sieve.size() ; ++i ) if( sieve[i] )
          for( auto j = i*i ; j < sieve.size() ; j += i ) sieve[j] = false ;

    std::vector<int> primes ;
    for( std::size_t i = 2 ; i < sieve.size() ; ++i )
        if( sieve[i] ) primes.push_back(i) ;
    return primes ;
}
```

Comment: Would be even faster if you can use an array instead of collections

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is not pitch-perfect, it would take less than **3 seconds** to execute. **Code in C#**.  
Step 1- omitted numbers which are divisible by 2,3, 5,7 
 Step 2 - To check prime number we don't need to divide given number with all the numbers. using square root will reduce the code to half time.

```
    using System;


namespace ProjectEuler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long i, j, sum = 17;
            bool flag = true;
            for (i = 2; i < 2000000; i++)
            {
                if ((i % 2) != 0 && (i % 3) != 0 && (i % 5) != 0 && (i % 7) != 0)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    for (j = 2; j <= Math.Sqrt(i); j++)
                    {
                        if (i % j == 0)
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == true)
                    {
                        sum = sum + i;
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Addition of prime No upto 2 million below is the code. 
     Please let me know    if anyone have doubt.

    <html>

    <body>

    <input id="inp" width="200px"/>
     <input type="button" onClick="onPress()" value="Check"/>

     </body>



      <script>
     function onPress()
      {


       var value= document.getElementById("inp").value;

         var arr=[2,3,5,7], add=17;

       for(var divisor=2; divisor<value; divisor++)
       {
        var prime= true
        if(divisor%2==0 || divisor%3==0 || divisor%5==0 || divisor%7==0)
           {


            prime=false;



             }



                if(prime !=false)
                {

               for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
                {
               if(divisor%arr[j]==0)
                 {

             prime=false;

                }

                }
                }


                if(prime==true)
                  {

                 arr.push(divisor);

                 add+= divisor;


                         }
                        }

                      console.log(add);


                        }





       </script>



       </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please format the code towards more readability, with indentation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my javascript solution:

```
function sumPrimes(num) {

  // determine if a number is prime
  function isPrime(n) {
    if (n === 2) return true;
    if (n === 3) return true;
    if (n % 2 === 0) return false;
    if (n % 3 === 0) return false;

    var  i = 5;
    var  w = 2;
    while (i * i <= n) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        i += w;
        w = 6 - w;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // subtract 1 for 'not being prime' in my context
  var sum = isPrime(num) ? num - 1 : -1;

  for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (isPrime(x) === true) {
      sum += x;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check the following code in c:

```
/*Program to print sum of all prime numbers upto 2000000*/

/*To check whether a number is prime or not it takes n^2 time by
  brute force but this program is sqrt(n) according to
  mathematical rules to check prime number efficiently.
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 2000000
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  unsigned long int prod=0;
  int prime;
  for(i=2;i<=MAX;i++){
    prime=1;
    for(j=2;j<(int)(sqrt(i)+1);j++){
      if(i%j==0){
        prime=0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(prime==1){
      prod=prod+i;
    }
  }
  printf("%ld",prod);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @DavidPostill OP hasn't been online for the last 2 years; I doubt their going to read this.

Comment: I've removed the blog link as it has no extra content (no explanation, only the code shown here), so added no value to the answer