# Project euler number 10 in C

Tags: c

i cant get the following code to run, ie it dosent give out any output

the objective is to find the sum of all primes below 2 million,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int is_prime(long long int i)
    {
        long long int n;
        if(i==2)
            return 1;
        for(n=2;n<=sqrt(i);n++)
            if(i%n==0)
            return 0;
        return 1;

    }

    int main()
    {
        long long int s=0,i=2;

        for(i<2000000;i++;)
        {
            if(is_prime(i))
                s=s+i;
        }
        printf("sum: %lli",s);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So you want your code dump to be debugged and fixed?

Comment: Try this inside the loop: `if (i % 10000 == 0) { putchar('#'); flush(stdout); }` to see how fast it goes (1 `#` every ten thousand numbers).

Comment: Is there a question there somewhere?

Comment: Take a look at this and see if you can spot any problems: `for(i<2000000;i++;)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157322/find-the-sum-of-all-the-primes-below-two-million-project-euler-c

Comment: @pmg : the # was a good idea. thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 2):

You're using the for loop wrong.  A for loop looks like this:

```
for(initialization; test expression; update)
```

But you wrote

```
for(i<2000000;i++;)
```

which should be

```
for(;i<2000000;i++)
```

ie, skip initialization, on each iteration test for i<2000000 and increment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are essentially factorising every integer up to two million for this. It's not that your code isn't working, it just is running very very slowly. If you attach a debugger to it you will most likely be at line

```
if(i%n==0)
```

most of the time.

Implement the [Sieve of Eratostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Will be the most effective here.

Also your loop `for(i<2000000;i++;)` will run for `2^64` cycles.